# More or less information in hover on synonymed tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms, information-display

I've found that the hover for a synonym of a tag, not only doesn't tell you that it's a synonym directly (though seeing no quantity for it clues you in), but it also has a `synonyms` link.

The original tag doesn't have the `synonyms` link.

I now know that that will tell me if it's synonymed (for when I'm on a place that doesn't have the quantities next to the tags), but it seems backwards in meaning.

A synonymed tag doesn't have synonyms, only the original tag has synonyms.

My suggestion would be to put the usual (s) symbol somewhere in the hover, and switch which hover has the `synonyms` link.  Another alternative would be to rename the link to something else, maybe `original` or `parent tag`.

As an example (of existing), here is the `question` tag hover, which is a synonym:

[image: Question Tag Hover]

And here is the `questions` tag, which is the original:

[image: Questions Tag Hover]

And yes, *I recognize this is a small thing*.

Comment: Why is it relevant that the tag is actually a synonym when looking at the hover information? That seems like something of an implementation detail, not something that users have to be overly concerned with. I don't necessarily *oppose* making this change, but I'm not sure why it would be beneficial.

Comment: @Cody, It's not critical, just a little confusing.  Like when they're trying to decide what tag to use, but of course whichever they decide will lead to the same route.  I always think things should be as clear as possible, and confusion minimized.  It makes for a better user experience, and decreases frustration.  Like I said, a small thing.  bemace has a good point about subscribing.  I've found that I'm subscribed to synonyms sometimes, because I didn't know they were synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Do we need to know it's a synonym, or that synonyms even exist in this context? It seems to me like it should be totally transparent, with synonym popups looking just like the popup for the real tag they point to.

The only source of confusion I see is if someone tries to subscribe to a synonym of a tag they already subscribed to. Then a message explaining about the synonyms might be useful.